# my cake php app can not translate by using I18N when running on Linux host

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I used I18N for localization. (I specified two languages: english and japanese). It runs well on localhost.
But when I upload all files to Linux Host, it crashed!!!. It just can not translate.
Help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that I have to delete tmp files in app/tmp/cache/persistent and app/tmp/cache/models. It solved my problem.